# How to show our cost on front-end for Admin accounts?

Tags: admin, frontend

Wondering how to show cost on the front end for Admin accounts (when signed in of course). This is so reps viewing the website can see price we sell for as well as our cost. Has anyone done anything like this? Any insight would be appreciated - thanks!

http://ledt8bulb.com/keystone-direct-drive-4-foot-15w-t8-led-tube-4000k.html

Answer (score 0):

this code is only for product page `view.phtml`.

```
<?php  
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getCost(), 'cost');
}
?>
```